# autocompletebox without highlighted border

Tags: c#, silverlight, autocomplete

I have an [autocompletebox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that I am trying to remove the border from.  Just setting the border to a transparent color or a border thickness of zero isn't good enough, because when the box is moused over, a secondary border appears.  The [style template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728668%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the control is cryptic enough for me that my guesses on changing different parameters have not resulted in border changes.

What do I need to do to disable the border for this control?

Comment: ...what about the other [AutoCompleteBox states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728668(v=vs.95).aspx#sectionToggle1)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is due to the FocusVisualElement component in styletemplates for controls.
I can see that the Autocompletebox doesn't have this component, but the Autocompletebox itself is built with more basic controls who do have such an element in their style template.

Try making a style for a textbox without the focusvisualelement (remove it completely from the template) and let the textbox inside the Autocompletebox make use of that template, that should remove the border from the autocompletebox.

Answer (score 0):

So the style contained a control template with the textbox used in the autocomplete user control... I just replaced the style specifically for that textbox to show a transparent border on the mouseover state.